# Why is the first component of the energy-momentum tensor $-p_a v^a$?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, metric-tensor

A single particle of mass $m$ travels along a geodesic curve in flat spacetime. A tangent vector $u^a$ to this geodesic, parameterised by the parameter $\tau = \int \left( \eta_{\mu \nu}u^\mu u^\nu \right)^{1/2}$, is referred to as the 4-velocity of the particle. Furthermore, due to this choice of parameter, it can be shown that:

$$
u_a u^a \equiv \eta_{\mu \nu} u^\mu u^\nu = -1
$$

For clarity, abstract index notation is used, along with setting $c = 1$.

Furthermore, the energy—momentum vector $p^a$ for said particle is defined as:

$$
p^a = mu^a
$$

The book I’m reading (General Relativity by Wald) says that the energy $E$ of the particle, measured by an observer with its own 4-velocity $v^a$, is defined as:

$$
E = -p_a v^a
$$

This equation is followed with the statement:

> Thus, in special relativity, energy is recognized to be the “time component” of the 4-vector $p^a$.

Here is where I get lost. The statement makes it sound like this is obvious, but I’m struggling to prove this from the equations given.

Basically, in a given Cartesian coordinate system, we have two geodesic curves along with one energy-momentum vector for each curve - $u^a$ for the particle and $v^a$ for the observer. The energy of the particle as measured by the observer is thus given by:

$$
E = -p_a v^a = -\eta_{\mu \nu}p^\mu v^\nu = mu^0v^0 - mu^1v^1 - mu^2v^2 - mu^3v^3
$$

However, the first component of $p$ is simply:

$$
p^0 = mu^0
$$

I don’t see how this can equate with the energy under general circumstances without further restrictions on $v$. I haven’t yet used the fact that $u_a u^a = v_a v^a = -1$, but any attempt in doing so only seems to complicate things - for example, substituting $u^0 = \sqrt{1 + (u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2 + (u^3)^2}$.

So my question is: How does the above definition of the energy $E$ lead to the first component of $p$ being $E$? I’ve seen proofs of this for other definitions but am interested in how this can be derived from the above definition, where energy is the contraction of the particle energy-momentum tensor with the 4-velocity of the observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that this number $E$ is the *time-component of the vector $p$, as calculated by an observer with velocity $v$*. So, the very notion of 'the time-component of a vector' is a-priori meaningless; it only acquires meaning once you specify an observer, hence it is an observer-dependent notion. The observer tells us what they consider to be pure time components, and what they deem to be pure spatial components. Here is a simple linear algebraic fact which will hopefully clarify things:

> Let $(V,g)$ be an arbitrary $(n+1)$-dimensional Lorentzian inner product space, and let $v\in V$ be a normalized (for convenience) timelike vector i.e $g(v,v)=-1$. Let $T=\text{span}\{v\}$, and let $S:=T^{\perp}=\{w\in V\,:\, g(w,v)=0\}$ be the orthogonal complement with respect to $g$. Then, $S$ is a spacelike subspace and we have a $g$-orthogonal direct sum decomposition $V=T\oplus S$.

It is a good exercise for you to prove this statement. Here, the timelike vector $v\in V$ plays the role of the instantaneous velocity vector of an observer. Then, this observer's velocity allows us to decompose the vector space $V$ (in general it will be the tangent space at a specific spacetime point) into two mutually orthogonal pieces: $V=T\oplus T^{\perp}=T\oplus S$. The first summand $T$ is a timelike subspace, and it is spanned by the observer's velocity (so is $1$-dimensional), while the second summand $S$ is an $n$-dimensional spacelike subspace of $V$. The elements of the subspace $T$ is what the observer would consider to be 'purely temporal', while vectors in $S$ are what this particular observer would call 'purely spatial'.

So, given any $\xi\in V$, **there exist unique $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$, and $s\in S$** such that
\begin{align}
\xi&=\alpha v+s.
\end{align}
In fact, you can show that $\alpha=-g(\xi,v)$ and $s=\xi-[-g(\xi,v)v]=\xi+g(\xi,v)v$. So, given an arbitrary vector $\xi$, we decomposed it (with respect to the observer!) into a purely temporal portion $av\in T$ and a purely spatial portion $s\in S$.

In your case, you're starting with a vector $p$ (interpreted as 4-momentum), and you're decomposing it relative to an observer's instantaneous velocity vector $v$:
\begin{align}
p&=Ev+\vec{p},
\end{align}
for some unique number $E\in\Bbb{R}$ and some unique vector $\vec{p}\in S$. This is literally the same statement as above, with different notation. So, the number $E=-g(p,v)=-g_{ab}p^av^b=-p_av^a$, which a-priori is just obtained via a linear-algebraic direct sum, is now given the physical interpretation as the energy as measured by an observer.

---

**Edit:**

If you don't like direct sums and prefer to think in terms of bases, then here's the explanation. You can't just take an arbitrary basis $\{e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ such that $g(e_a,e_b)=\eta_{ab}$ for all $a,b$ (i.e an 'orthonormal basis'), and then expect that relative to this basis, the number $E$ will equal $p^0$. You have to involve the observer by decomposing vectors with respect to a basis where the first (timelike) vector is the observer's velocity: $\{v,s_1,s_2,s_3\}$, such that $g(v,v)=-1, g(v,s_i)=0, g(s_i,s_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

So, in your post when you talk about a Cartesian coordinate system blablabla, what you missed out is that the coordinate system has to be 'adapted' to the observer in the above sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the exact “restriction on $v$” I was looking for.  Is the reason why the coordinates are chosen in such a way because the observer “stands still spatially” in their own coordinate system? After all, we often draw observers as coordinate systems. I’m just trying to understand why this wasn’t mentioned in the book. As you’re saying, $E$ is coordinate-dependent, which is exactly why I couldn’t make it work, except when $v = (1, 0, 0, 0)$, in which case it works as expected. (Thinking in terms of direct sums is completely fine as well!)

Comment: @Max yes exactly, the observer views themselves as being completely still at each instant (the word 'instant' is a loose way of saying at each tangent space), and only 'move through time', hence they make measurements with respect to their direct sum decomposition $V=T\oplus T^{\perp}$. In Minkowski space, you can think of $T^{\perp}$ (and its affine translations) as being the hyperplanes of simultaneity for the observer. In other words, they set up a time axis along the subspace $T$, and set up spatial axes along $T^{\perp}$.

Comment: For the general case, this decomposition is only occurring in each tangent space (i.e the observer has at each instant a notion of 'infinitesimal' time and space displacements), so you'd need something like Frobenius' theorem in order to 'integrate' these tangent hyperplanes to get an actual submanifold in spacetime that we can call 'hypersurfaces of simultaneity for the observer'. Btw, you may want to check out Robert Geroch's *Mathematical Physics* text; there's a short ~10 page section on Minkowski space/SR which goes through some of these types of math-to-physics translations.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton for your help! I think it finally makes sense now. And thanks for the tip! I’ll give it a shot!