# Why is the energy of a particle with $4$-momentum $p^a = mu^a$ measured by an observer with $4$-velocity $v^a$ given by $E=-p_av^a$?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, momentum, velocity, observers

On page 61 of his book “General Relativity”, Robert Wald says that the energy of a particle with $4$-momentum $p^a = mu^a$ measured by an observer with $4$-velocity $v^a$ is given by $E=-p_av^a$. How can I see that?

Comment: See [Why is the first component of the energy-momentum tensor $-p_av^a$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/718360/203278) for some remarks. You can take that as a definition of the phrase “energy of a particle measured by an observer”, but to see that this is a reasonable definition I like the approach presented in Landau and Lifshitz, starting with the Lagrangian for a point particle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761369/2451