# Energy is the time component of 4-momentum in SR: Proof as per R. Wald's book

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, observers

[image]

This is an excerpt fom R. Wald's book on General Relativity (page 61). I'm not able to understand how he deduces that $E$ must be the time component of $p^a$ with only the assertions made before this part of the book.

The four velocity ($u^a$) is defined as the tangent to a timelike curve parametrized by the proper time ($\tau$) defined as
$
\tau = \int \left(-\eta_{ab}T^a T^b\right)^{1/2} dt
$

where $T^a$ is the tangent to the curve parametrized by any arbitrary parameter $t$.

$u^a u_a = -1$ is implied by the above parametrization.

That is the only information available. He says it like its obvious without giving any reason for it. What am I missing?

Comment: See [Why is the first component of the energy-momentum tensor $-p_av^a$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/718360/203278)

Comment: See my replies to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761369/walds-definition-of-energy-of-a-massive-particle and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506106/how-does-p-cdot-u-relate-to-observed-energy-and-momentum-for-a-massive-particl